# Como detectar o dataset selecionado em um charts

Tags: angularjs, chartjs

estou usando o seguinte código para detectar o dataset, porem o `INDEX` vem errado, onde o valor seria o index do charts e não do dataset. Preciso recuperar a label do dataset correspondente ao que cliquei no charts.

```
function GetChartLabel(events, click, dataset) {
  var event = events[0];
  if (event) {
    var activePoints = event._chart.controller.getElementsAtEvent(click);
    var chartData = activePoints[0]._chart.config.data;
    var idx = activePoints[0]._index;
    var label = chartData.datasets[idx].label;
  }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema aplicando o `getElementAtEvent` ao invés do `getElementsAtEvent`.

A função ficou assim:

```
var activePoint = event._chart.controller.getElementAtEvent(click);
var _datasetIndex = activePoint[0]._datasetIndex;
var label = chartData.datasets[_datasetIndex].label;
```